# Clear the renderer from a Grid column in Vaadin 8.1

Tags: datagrid, vaadin, renderer, vaadin8

In [Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/framework) 8.1 app, on the [Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid) widget, how does one clear a [column renderer](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.renderer) after setting it?

We can set a renderer on a [`Grid.Column`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html) by calling [`setRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setRenderer-com.vaadin.ui.renderers.Renderer-). How to un-set it?

Passing `null` results in a null pointer exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Renderer can not be null

The default behavior before setting the renderer seems to be simply calling `toString` on the column’s objects.

➟ How get back to that default behavior?

Comment: What is your use case for clearing the renderer? Or for changing the renderer after the column was created?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich User wants to change their view of the data. Switch time zone on date-time values, or convert money across currencies, or rounding numbers for easier scanning vs showing precise amount for accuracy, or show number in scientific notation or not, or change scheme for using icon characters such as RottenTomatoes.com tomato-meter, and on and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to ask Vaadin to revert to default.

Before setting the new renderer, you can ask for the existing default renderer.

```
Renderer<?> r = this.columnInstant.getRenderer() ;
```

Then later re-apply it.

```
myGridColumn.setRenderer( r ) ;
```

Commonly, the default renderer is [`com.vaadin.ui.renderers.TextRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/TextRenderer.html). You can instantiate a new one if that is more convenient than retaining a reference to the old one.

```
myGridColumn.setRenderer( new com.vaadin.ui.renderers.TextRenderer() ) ;
```